# Using PHP to upload an activity to Strava using API v3

Tags: php, curl

I'm working on an application in which I'd like to be able to upload activities (GPX files) to Strava using it's API v3.

My application successfully handles the OAuth process - I'm able to request activities, etc, successfully.

However, when I try to upload an activity - it fails.

Here's the relevant sample of my code:

```
// $filename is the name of the GPX file
// $actual_file contains the full path

$actual_file = realpath($filename);
$url="https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads";
$postdata = "activity_type=ride&file=". "@" . $actual_file . ";filename=" . $filename . "&data_type=gpx";

$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $strava_access_token);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Here's what I get in response:

```
{"message":"Bad Request", "errors":[{"resource":"Upload", "field":"file","code":"not a file"}]}
```

I then tried this:

```
// $filename is the name of the GPX file
// $actual_file contains the full path

$actual_file = realpath($filename);

$url="https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads";

$postfields = array(
    "activity_type" => "ride",
    "data_type" => "gpx",
    "file" => "@" . $filename
);
$postdata = http_build_query($postfields);

$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $strava_access_token, "Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postfields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);

$json = curl_exec ($ch);
$error = curl_error ($ch);
```

Here's what I get in response:

```
{"message":"Bad Request", "errors":[{"resource":"Upload", "field":"data","code":"empty"}]}
```

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong when trying to pass the GPX file.

Is it possible to provide a bit of sample PHP code to show how this should work?

For what it's worth - I'm fairly certain the GPX file is valid (it's actually a file I downloaded using Strava's export feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that answering my own question less than one day after posting it isn't bad form. But I've got it working, so I may as well, just in case anyone else finds it useful...

```
// $filename is the name of the file
// $actual_file includes the filename and the full path to the file
// $strava_access_token contains the access token

$actual_file = realpath($filename);

$url="https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads";

$postfields = array(
    "activity_type" => "ride",
    "data_type" => "gpx",
    "file" => '@' . $actual_file . ";type=application/xml"
);

$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $strava_access_token);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$response = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Apparently, it's important ***not to include*** the `CURLOPT_POST` option.

Comment: can you please explain this a bit more..? I get the same response (code: not a file) in Android

Answer (score 0):

[Here is also a working Python example](https://gist.github.com/paulsoning/a376186560cbaf1bdc68701fce7e3d47)

```
import os
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'authorization': 'Bearer <Token>',
    }

dir = os.getcwd() + '/files/'
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    file = open(dir + filename, 'rb') 
    files = {
        "file": (filename, file, 'application/gpx+xml'),
        "data_type": (None, 'gpx'),
    }

    try:
        response = requests.post('http://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads',files=files, headers=headers)
        print(filename)
        print(response.text)
        print(response.headers)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  # This is the correct syntax
        print(e)
        sys.exit(1)
```